# Random generates same number in java

Tags: java, random

This is my java code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class search
{
  private int numelem;
   private int[] input=new int[100];

public void setNumofelem()
{

  System.out.println("Enter the total numebr of elements");
  Scanner yz=new Scanner(System.in);
  numelem=yz.nextInt();

}
public void randomnumber() throws Exception
{
int max=500,min=1,n=numelem;
   Random rand = new Random(); 
 for (int j=0;j < n;j++)
 {

   input[j]=rand.nextInt(max)+1;

} 
}

public void printinput()
{ 
  int b=numelem,t=0;
  while(true)
if(b!=0)
{
   System.out.print("  "+input[t]);
     b--;
     t++;
}
else
break;
}

}
public class mycode
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{

   search a=new search();
   a.setNumofelem();
   a.randomnumber();
   a.printinput();
}
}
```

Now the function `randomnumber()` just returns the same number.The function executes perfectly if I execute  it as a separate java program but fails miserably if I call it using an object.I have also tried the following variations but nothing works everything return the same number.

**Variation 1:**

```
public void randomnumber() throws Exception
    {
    int max=500,min=1,n=numelem;
       Random rand = new Random(); 
     for (int j=0;j < n;j++)
     {

            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

       input[j]=rand.nextInt(max)+1;

    } 
    }
```

**Variation 2:**

```
 public void randomnumber() throws Exception
    {
    int max=500,min=1,n=numelem;
       Random rand = new Random(); 
     for (int j=0;j < n;j++)
     {

    rand.setSeed(System.nanoTime());

       input[j]=rand.nextInt(max)+1;

    } 
    }
```

**Variation 3:**

```
 public void randomnumber() throws Exception
    {
    int max=500,min=1,n=numelem;
       Random rand = new Random(); 
     for (int j=0;j < n;j++)
     {

            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    rand.setSeed(System.nanoTime());

       input[j]=rand.nextInt(max)+1;

    } 
    }
```

**Sample input/Output:**

Enter the number of elements:

5

23 23 23 23 23 23

Comment: "please ignore the variables which are not used" - no, please don't post code that isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: I've just tested the *Variation 2* and worked fine.

Comment: in `printinput` you are always retrieving one and the same element since `t` doesn't change... simply replace the `while`, `b`, `if`, ... with a simple `for` loop over `t`

Comment: The problem is nothing to do with `Random`, it's that you've written your `printinput` method in a really bizarre way, and so introduced a bug **there**.  (Thus voting to close as "simple typo".)

Comment: This is yet another Stack Overflow case where learning to use a debugger rather than asking others to do it for you would have saved everybody a lot of time and been more educational all round.

Comment: Also, try to use an IDE with auto-formatting. It will help you a **lot**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not *random*. The problem is in your `printinput()` method.

You are printing the same element on each iteration, because you are never changing the index you are using to access to the array.

**How can you solve it?** Increase the index `t` on each iteration. Also, using a simple `for` loop to print the array content will be better and easier to read:

```
public void printinput()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numelem; i++) {
        System.out.print("  " + input[i]);
    }
}
```

**Note:** I would strongly recommend you to follow Java naming conventions. Use `mixedCase` for methods/variables and use `CamelCase` for classes/interfaces.

Comment: Alternatively, just write a sensible `for` loop.

Comment: @Christian I actually have that t++ forgot to paste it now the code has been edited.Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @user1613360 well, it solved the problem for me. I will take a look to the edit.

Comment: @user1613360: So now your code works fine.

Comment: @Christian: This is the correct answer, but this question should arguably just be closed as "simple typographical error".

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Nope it doesn't anyways I will figure it out on my own because these days people here are more interested in criticizing than helping out had a wonderful experience thanks.For the record I don't post question without trying and I will always try to google and find the solution before asking them.

Comment: @user1613360: Yes it does: http://ideone.com/7PtVpK

Comment: @user1613360 I thought I was trying to help you. Anyways, this should have solved your problem. Try to save, compile and run your `.java` file again.

Comment: @Chrisitian Maybe I should check for possible errors in my entire code anyways thanks.